# Laravel, consulta a base de datos con WHERE no se concatena con otros

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

**Versión de Laravel: 7**

Buenas tardes, antes tenía una forma de filtrar mediante get, primero hace traía todos los registros de un modelo. Por ejemplo:

```
$ads = Ad::where('adtype_id', $b_tipo)->orderBy('date_created', 'DESC');
```

Esto me devuelve todo el query builder para todos los elementos donde `adtype_id` sea igual a 1 o 2.

Si hago un `dd($ads->get())` todo bien, son los que coinciden, el problema es cuando luego quiero hacer añadir un where a la variable `$ads` (cosa que antes me funcionaba)

```
$ads = Ad::where('adtype_id', $b_tipo)->orderBy('date_created', 'DESC');

if($request->b){
    $ads = $ads->where('title', 'like', '%'.$request->b.'%')
               ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%'.$request->b.'%');
}


if($request->departamento){
    $ads = $ads->where('department_id', '=', $request->departamento);
}

 if($request->provincia){
    $ads = $ads->where('province_id', $request->provincia);
}
if($request->distrito){
    $ads = $ads->where('district_id', $request->distrito);
}
```

Lo hago de esta forma porque puede que tenga o no filtro por distrito, por titulo o por fecha.
El problema es que cuando hago la consulta de esta forma está ignorando los filtros anteriores (adtype_id), esto antes me funcionaba, no cambié versión de Laravel ni nada.

Al final del código tengo un `paginate()` por eso no hago el `get` en esas consultas, igual el problema como dije es cuando hago el `where` (ya le hice un dump)

También acepto sugerencias de cómo podría mejorar la función del filtro.

Comment: Entonces ¿los últimos 3 filtros son opcionales?

Comment: @BetaM se puede decir que son opcionales dependiendo del filtro que elijan, si yo pongo Ads del tipo 1 y que sean de menos de 4 días solo me trae eso, si adicional agrego una búsqueda me trae las que coincidan. Toda la lógica ya está y antes funcionaba, solo quiero saber qué estoy haciendo mal en el query

Comment: Puedes probar como en la doc se propone donde existen dentro de un array todas las posibles evaluaciones, donde veas esto: `->where([....................])` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Puede ser por ese `orWhere` que pones en el ámbito global de la consulta. Dale una mirada a lo que se recomienda en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-where-clauses) sobre las cláusulas `orWhere`: "Siempre debe agrupar las llamadas orWhere para evitar comportamientos inesperados cuando se aplican ámbitos globales."

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ sería muy bueno una respuesta que oriente al OP y que de paso sirva como solución para los demás

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que posiblemente esté haciendo que la consulta ignore las demás cláusulas `where`, es que tienes un `orWhere` en el ámbito global de la consulta. Me refiero a esta línea:

```
$ads = $ads->where('title', 'like', '%'.$request->b.'%')
    ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%'.$request->b.'%');
```

Eso va a hacer que independientemente de lo que pongas en otras cláusulas, la consulta te devuelva todos los registros que cumplan la condición `orWhere`.

Para resolverlo puedes agrupar esa cláusula `orWhere`. Puedes hacerlo así:

```
$ads = $ads->where(function($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%'.$request->b.'%')
        ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%'.$request->b.'%');
});
```

Referencia: [Parameter Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#parameter-grouping)
Específicamente esta nota: "Siempre debe agrupar las llamadas `orWhere` para evitar comportamientos inesperados cuando se aplican ámbitos globales."

---

Como sugerencia, para no poner `if`s  la consulta, puedes hacerlo de la "forma laravel" con [Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses).

> En ocasiones, es posible que desee que se apliquen determinadas cláusulas de consulta a una consulta en función de otra condición. Por ejemplo, es posible que solo desee aplicar una instrucción `where` si un valor de entrada dado está presente en la solicitud HTTP entrante. Puede lograr esto usando el método `when`.

Por ejemplo:

```
$b = $request->b;
$departamento = $request->departamento;
$provincia = $request->provincia;
$distrito = $request->distrito;

$ads = Ad::where('adtype_id', $b_tipo)->orderBy('date_created', 'DESC')
    ->when($b, function ($query, $b) {
        return $query->where(function($q) use ($b) {
            $q->where('title', 'like', '%'.$b.'%')
                ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%'.$b.'%');
        });
    })
    ->when($departamento, function ($query, $departamento) {
        return $query->where('department_id', '=', $departamento);
    })
    ->when($provincia, function ($query, $provincia) {
        return $query->where('province_id', $provincia);
    })
    ->when($distrito, function ($query, $distrito) {
        return $query->where('district_id', $distrito);
    })
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Está funcionando bien ahora.

Comment: @AndySamuel Genial. Agregué un bonus, que es cómo lo hago cuando tengo cláusulas opcionales en la consulta. Saludos.

Comment: Muy bueno el consejo, no conocía esa forma de hacer la condición